# porque cuando intento hacer un binding entre componentes de angular el valor no se muestra en el .html pero si en la consola

Tags: angular, binding

estoy haciendo un binding entre 2 componentes de angular, tengo lo siguiente:

Este es el codigo completo de mis 2 componentes:

Esto es de la componente 1:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';

import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  z: number=0;

  url: string = "http://crm.seaconfiable.com/upload/";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(resultToken => {
          //do whatever you want to do with the token
          //i.e. Save the token in the localstorage like this -
          localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken.access_token);
          return this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken);
        })
      )
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.cargarJson(result);
          },error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }

    /*this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log("-----------_>"+result.data);
      },error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );*/

  /*
  anteriorInmueble(){
    (this.i<=0) ? this.i=680: this.i=this.i-5;
    console.log("AntIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);


  siguienteInmueble(){
    (this.i>=680) ? this.i=0: this.i=this.i+5;
    console.log("SigIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);
  }*/


// metodo para cargar el Json recibido de la petición
  cargarJson(result){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var precio: number=0;
    var i,j: number=1;

                for(const item of result.data) {
                    var pos: number=0;          //variable que define la posicion a almacenar en el vector
                    pos =0;
                    console.log("POS----->"+pos);
                    var inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.fotos = [];
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id_c;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    precio = item.price;
                    precio = Math.round(precio*100)/100;
                    inmueble.precio = precio;
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot01_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot02_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot03_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot04_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot05_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot06_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot07_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot08_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot09_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot10_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot11_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot12_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot13_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot14_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot15_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot16_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot17_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot18_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot19_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot20_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      if(pos == 0){
                        inmueble.fotos[pos]="n";
                      }
                    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);  //se almacena el inmueble en el vector de inmuebles

            }
            console.log("************:"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);


    }

    anteriorInmueble(){
      (this.z<=0)? this.z=680: this.z=this.z-1;
    }


    siguienteInmueble(){
      (this.z>=680)? this.z=0: this.z=this.z+1;
    }



  consultarPais(){

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div> <span class="text-hot">
          <b>HOT</b> </span> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="text-hot align-middle">
              list
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--<div *ngIf="inmuebles!=null; else espera">-->
  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z].id}}_{{inmuebles[z].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio: {{inmuebles[i].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[0]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal> <!-- ***  BINDING **** -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].nombre}}</h1> -->
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+1].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}</h1>
              <div class="card-body">

                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+1].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              
              <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[0]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+2].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+2].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+2].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
               <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[0]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+3].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+3].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+3].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
            
              <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[0]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+4].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+4].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+4].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[5]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+5].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <!-- <h1>{{inmuebles[z+5].nombre}}</h1> -->

                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+5].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+5].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              
              <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[6]" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--</div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>-->
</div>
```

Este es el còdio de mi otra componente:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() prueba: Inmueble;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   console.log("=============="+this.prueba.nombre);
  }

  

}
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert"> <h1> HOLA {{prueba.nombre}} </h1></div>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-row">

    <div class="d-inline-flex" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ml-2" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ml-2" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/4.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    </div>

    <div class="" id="cont-descripcion">
      <p class="text-center">Descripcion</p>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Ubicacion: </th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bath fa-2x "></i> <p> Baños: 1 <p> </td>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-hot-tub fa-2x"></i> <p> Baños de Servicio: 1 <p> </td>

          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bed fa-2x"></i> <p> Habitaciones: 2 <p> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-ruler fa-2x "></i> <br/>metros construidos: 100</td>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-ruler fa-2x "></i> <br/>metros de terreno: 100</td>
          <td class="text-center"> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chVerTutoriales" onclick="btTutorial.disabled = !this.checked"><br/>Pago Condominio</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Caractetisticas Adicionales</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi gran problema es que no me quiere mostrar los valores en el .html, fijense que en el .ts tengo un Console.log del valor y eso si me lo imprime con sus valores, pero el problema esta en el .html, no imprime nada. cual es el problema? tengo horas en esto y no logro solucionar. agradeceria su ayuda. gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te sale en pantalla, simplemente "Hola"?

Comment: Si, simplemente "Hola", el valor de la variable no, y en la consola si me lo muestra, no entiendo porque.

Answer (score 0):

Reproducí tu código y me marcó error al inicializar la variable, por lo que realicé lo siguiente:

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
    inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];

    constructor(){
        this.inmuebles.push(new Inmueble());
        this.inmuebles[0].nombre = "jose";
    }
}
```

Como no tienes ningún objeto, no se le asigna nada y por esa razón el binding no se ve reflejado.

Comment: Hola Carlos. Eso que escribiste creo que ya lo estoy haciendo, solo que no escribi el detalle. lo tengo asi:                     var inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.fotos = [];
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;

                        inmueble.fotos[pos]="n";
                      
                    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);  //se almacena el inmueble en el vector de inmuebles

Comment: No veo nada extraño en tu código para que no funcione el binding, siento que nombre está siendo null o undefined y por eso sólo muestra "Hola". Revisa si item.nomb_prod_c es null o undefined. A mi me funcionó bien el binding.

Comment: el item.nomb_prodc_c esta lleno con un nombre, y el gran problema es que por console.log si me lo imprime, el problema es al hacer el binding, no logro entender que esta pasando.

Comment: Entonces el error es más sutil y no creo que se pueda encontrar con el código que has publicado ya que a mi me funcionó realizando solo esa pequeña modificación.

Comment: termine colocando los codigos completos a ver si puedes ayudarme a identificar el problema amigo.

Comment: Podrías poner tus salidas de consola, ¿qué se imprime?